# replace nested for loop with array helpers - finding priority element

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript

I am looking to replace **nested for loop** implementation with array helpers for optimization,

The function returns string from testArray,  which contains the highest priority as per priorityArray.

```
const arr1 = ["A_COUNTY","B_STATE","C_COUNTRY", "D_CONTINENT","E_WORLD"]; 
const arr2 = ["X_COUNTY","Y_STATE","Z_PLANET"];
const priorityArray = ["CONTINENT","COUNTRY","STATE","COUNTY"];

function findPriorityElement(testArray:string[])
{
  for (let i = 0; i <priorityArray.length; i++)
    for (let j = 0; j <testArray.length; j++) {
      if (testArray[j].includes(priorityArray[i])) 
         return testArray[j];
    }

return "";
}

console.log(findPriorityElement(arr1)); // Result: "D_CONTINENT"
console.log(findPriorityElement(arr2)); // Result: "Y_STATE"
```

Any leads is appreciated.

Comment: I would prefer `for..of` instead to avoid manual iteration, but since you're trying to get a nested value, using `for` really is the best method IMO. You *can* use array methods here, but it'll make things slightly more complicated than they need to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `find()` instead of the inner for loop

```js
const arr1 = ["A_COUNTY", "B_STATE", "C_COUNTRY", "D_CONTINENT", "E_WORLD"];
const arr2 = ["X_COUNTY", "Y_STATE", "Z_PLANET"];
const priorityArray = ["CONTINENT", "COUNTRY", "STATE", "COUNTY"];

function findPriorityElement(testArray) {
  for (p of priorityArray) {
    const match = testArray.find(e => e.includes(p));
    if (match) {
      return match;
    }
  }
}

console.log(findPriorityElement(arr1)); // Result: "D_CONTINENT"
console.log(findPriorityElement(arr2)); // Result: "Y_STATE"
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr1 = ["A_COUNTY", "B_STATE", "C_COUNTRY", "D_CONTINENT", "E_WORLD"];
const arr2 = ["X_COUNTY", "Y_STATE", "Z_PLANET"];
const priorityArray = ["CONTINENT", "COUNTRY", "STATE", "COUNTY"];

const findPriorityElement = testArray => {
  for (const priorityElement of priorityArray) {
      const elem = testArray.find(testElement => testElement.includes(priorityElement));
      if (elem) {
          return elem;
      }
  }
};

console.log(findPriorityElement(arr1)); // Result: "D_CONTINENT"
console.log(findPriorityElement(arr2)); // Result: "Y_STATE"
```

Comment: Isn't this just a copy of the answer I provided?

Comment: My one is an arrow function. And refactored variables with in a meaningful way! As well as this is done by myself!